# How to depict an OR and an AND graphically?

Tags: usability, user-behavior, layout, input

So currently I have this basic layout for my UI:

[image: currentLayoutUI]

Where the '1' and '2' would be replaced by icons depicting a type of place (eg. supermarket/restaurant respectively).

When the user first visits this view, top left (current location) is highlighted by default, so if they wanted to search supermarkets around their location, they would click '1' for instance. If they wanted to search for restaurants in a specific location then they could click the magnifying glass, type in the location and press '2'.

My question is, is it easily understandable, with just having this view in front of you, what you would need to do, is there a better way to distinguish between which options are OR/AND?

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: Theres no need for that. What you have is either (Search from the phones Location) or Search from a (Selected Location). After that if you click on Restaurants or Cafes or Bars etc your app should know what location should start searching from.

Comment: I feel I may have not described the situation well enough; the app knows fine, it is more from a user's perspective. Will the user know that above the line is location and below the line is place type and that they must select one from each? Is it intuitive enough>

Answer (score 2):

Did you take a look at Venn diagram? [image: venn diagram from google search]

They could be simplified into icons,  where AND could be two circles with the intersection filled with your theme color, and OR having the whole area. As long as they stay next to each other. I think they should be clear enough.

Or, just put AND OR in the icon.

Comment: Cleaver suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't see how this could be implemented for the four buttons in an intuitive manner?